# Execute query on enter php page

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I need a query to execute when entering a page (php). I've already added this to the top.

**Code:-**

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table_name` (`player_id`, `unit1`, `unit2`, `unit3`, `unit4`)
VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user']['id']."', 0, 0, 0, 0)");
```

When my users enter the page that contains that, the query should be executed. Yes database connection is included.

How do I fix this? (*also will it duplicate player_id*)?

Comment: are you getting any error on running that?

Comment: No, I see nothing at all. I've check chrome console and it doesn't display anything about the query, should I use ajax maybe?

Comment: if 'player_id' is primary key then you can not insert more than once with the same User_id...

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

First `mysql` is deprecated use `mysqli`.

Your query is fine how i can see, but your table could be a problem.

You should not have primary key on `player_id` if you wish to duplicate `player_id`. (Otherwise keep the primary key).

Also if you wish to have one `player_id` with those results (not multiple / duplicates), then you could create query in this way:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `table_name` (`player_id`, `unit1`, `unit2`, `unit3`, `unit4`) 
          VALUES ('".$_SESSION['user']['id']."', 0, 0, 0, 0) 
          ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `unit1`=0, `unit2`=0, `unit3`=0, `unit4`=0";
```

**UPDATE:**

Also there could be a problem that you are missing a database identifier at `mysql_query`:

`mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )`

like `mysql_query("MYQUERY", $mylinkISavedAtConnectingToDatabase);`

Comment: player_id is on primary key, but it's so weird it doesn't execute the query.

Comment: At those information you gave to us, it's okay, it should execute but there's possibility to have no affected rows because of duplicate primary key. Also there could be problem with connecting to database, or the table_name is invalid or you entered wrong parameters, or there's missing parameter that is needed (NOT NULL).

Comment: Also you could check why it's not execute with `mysql_error`.. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: @OmegaCebbo Check for update i posted within this answer, it may solve your problem...

Comment: Can you advance "$mylinkISavedAtConnectingToDatabase", what should it say there?

Comment: If you were connected to database like this `$link = mysql_connect('mysql_host', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password')` you should pass at `mysql_query("MYQUERY", $link);` the link of connection.

Comment: I just asked because I don't want the query to create duplicates. And btw, player_id is primary key.

Comment: Now, the end of the query looks like this. ('".$_SESSION['user']['id']."', 0, 0, 0, 0)", $con); is it correct?

Comment: No success so far, I know that my connection is correct. How can I display errors?

Comment: Use `mysql_query("YOURQUERY") or die ("Error in query: ".mysql_error());`